# Check MaxGsuiteAccounts using Admin Directory API

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I wanted to know where can we check total and currently used user accounts?

For example a month ago there was a `Feedback` button on lower right corner to get this info:

[Image showing all the user info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZvZY.png)

I know we can get customerCreationTime and country etc using following https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/admin/directory_v1/directory.customers.get. How can we get Gsuite edition, its State and MaxGoogleAppsAccounts etc?

We can check no. of users in Billing panel but I want to learn using API.

Any help?

Comment: Checked the [Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/) and found no API method that returns such properties. I think you'd have to resort to manual mode for now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's available via API calls. Not everything available in the console is available through the API's, unfortunately.